# SharePoint managed MetadataField with allow multiple values - values are not in sorted order

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, term-store, term-set

I have one Managed Metadata Field (With Allow Multiple Values Selected).

When I add multiple values to this field and save. These values are not getting sotrted by default.
Refer below Snapshot. Here `Latvia Riga` should be above `Lithuania Vilnius`. but it is present at the the last position.

[image]

I checked Term Store Management setting, It is set to use the default sort order according to current language.
Refer Below Span Shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you cannot sort a managed metadata column. The option setting for sort order only take effects on the order of terms in the term sets. In other words, if you set the default sort order according to current language, it sort the terms only when you are checking them in the term set. After you adding them to the column, you are not able to sort that column values by language.

Answer (score 0):

I believe OP is asking about the order that the values are sorted in within the column/field of a specific item that is tagged. Based on our experience, those get sorted by the order in which they were entered.